# pg_search with nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

I installed pg_search for the first time and I'm trying to create a search for Books and Chapters.  These are nested routes.

**routes.rb:**

```
resources :books do
  resources :chapters, except: [:index]
end
```

pgsearch results display the links to the information but the chapters link shows /chapters/17, when it should display /books/50/chapters/17.

**search index view:**

```
<h2>
 <%  @pg_searches.each do |pg_search| %>
  <p> <%= link_to pg_search.searchable.title, pg_search.searchable %> </p>
 <% end %>
<h2>
```

**SearchesController**

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

 def index
  @pg_searches = PgSearch.multisearch(params[:query])
 end
end
```

**chapter.rb**

```
include PgSearch
 multisearchable :against => [:title, :body]
```

**book.rb**

```
include PgSearch
 multisearchable :against => [:title, :description]
```

**Here's the error message:**

Couldn't find Book without an ID

```
def show
 **@book = Book.find(params[:book_id])**
 @chapters = Chapter.all
 @chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])
 @table_of_contents = @chapter.table_of_contents
```

How do I get the correct routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `link_to` path is missing the parent object in order to form the proper url.  Because the router wants a URL of the form  `books/:id/chapters/:id` , we also need to pass `link_to` for chapter a book object.

Try this:

https://gist.github.com/MichaelCPell/08fb6af5c27b0466366f

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to try [searching through associations](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#searching-through-associations)
or check similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398866/how-to-link-pgseaerch-results-to-index-page-in-nested-resources)

Comment: Tried associated_against, still receiving same results.